# What is the meaning of this TFS Source Control Explorer Extension folder arrow icon?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, icons, source-control-explorer

It's very hard to understand some misterious TFS Source Control Explorer Extension icons, they can cause assumptions that something is wrong. Can anyone tell me what are these for? There are no pending changes in this folder, it is correctly mapped and I have no clue of the meaning of such folder state.

[image: TFS Source Control Icons]

What about this one:

[image]

**Update about this 2nd icon: [This icon is displayed at files that are target of Branch operation or if file is branched only to one location.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-11508)**

Where can I find these states in TFS?

Comment: I could not find these icons in [The Visual Studio Image Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246582.aspx). Do you have a Visual Studio extension for TFS installed, like [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-13343)?

Comment: Uhm...yes, you're right! TFS Source Control Explorer Extension is the reason of these icons. Thank you! But I'm still wondering what is the meaning of them. I'll update the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Both icons indicate that the file/folder has been branched from somewhere. The first icon is for Folders, and the 2nd icon is for files.

If you want to disable branch-specific icons, then that can be set in **Tools > Options > TFS Source Control Explorer Extension > Files icon change = False**

[image: TFS Extension Settings]

You can see that the desription applies to branched content.

When I view my own branched folder with this setting on, you can see both icons:
[image: TFS Extension Branch Icons]

With this setting disabled, you can see the icons going back to normal:
[image: Normal TFS Icons]

Answer (score 0):

There is no corresponding icons in VS and TFS. It's the Customization of [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HolanJan.TFSSourceControlExplorerExtension-11508)

As mentioned in the **File icon change**:

The second is displayed at files that are target of Branch operation or if file is branched only to one location.

The first just simply stands for folders.